# Add Attributes to Table Cells with JQuery

Tags: html, jquery

Need a little help. I ran across this script (https://stackblitz.com/edit/mobile-table?file=index.html,index.js) that adds a label to every td (it makes a table mobile-friendly by reordering column headers with CSS pseudo selector).

I need the script to work on any class name with "table-mobile" (not every table by default). When I try duplicating the table with .table-mobile in the html, it only applies the label attributes to the first table and not the second table that I duplicated.

I am not a javascript developer but can usually get stuff to work with a little help. I got the class name working but hung up when adding the second table.

HTML

```
<table class="table-mobile">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Account</th>
      <th>Due Date</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Period</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Visa - 3412</td>
      <td>04/01/2016</td>
      <td>$1,190</td>
      <td>03/01/2016 - 03/31/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Visa - 6076</td>
      <td>03/01/2016</td>
      <td>$2,443</td>
      <td>02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Corporate AMEX</td>
      <td>03/01/2016</td>
      <td>$1,181</td>
      <td>02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Visa - 3412</td>
      <td>02/01/2016</td>
      <td>$842</td>
      <td>01/01/2016 - 01/31/2016</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table class="table-mobile">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Account</th>
    <th>Due Date</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Period</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Visa - 3412</td>
    <td>04/01/2016</td>
    <td>$1,190</td>
    <td>03/01/2016 - 03/31/2016</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Visa - 6076</td>
    <td>03/01/2016</td>
    <td>$2,443</td>
    <td>02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Corporate AMEX</td>
    <td>03/01/2016</td>
    <td>$1,181</td>
    <td>02/01/2016 - 02/29/2016</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Visa - 3412</td>
    <td>02/01/2016</td>
    <td>$842</td>
    <td>01/01/2016 - 01/31/2016</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<script>setMobileTable('.table-mobile')</script>
```

Javascript:

```
window.setMobileTable = function(selector) {
  // if (window.innerWidth > 600) return false;
  const tableEl = document.querySelector('.table-mobile');
  const thEls = tableEl.querySelectorAll('thead th');
  const tdLabels = Array.from(thEls).map(el => el.innerText);
  tableEl.querySelectorAll('tbody tr').forEach( tr => {
    Array.from(tr.children).forEach( 
      (td, ndx) =>  td.setAttribute('label', tdLabels[ndx])
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The line `const tableEl = document.querySelector('.table-mobile');` just selects the first element with the class .table-mobile.

You'll need to use `querySelectorAll()` and then loop through each one.

Try this

```
window.setMobileTable = function (selector) {
  // if (window.innerWidth > 600) return false;
  const tablesEl = document.querySelectorAll('.table-mobile');
  tablesEl.forEach((tableE1) => {
    const thEls = tableE1.querySelectorAll('thead th');
    const tdLabels = Array.from(thEls).map(el => el.innerText);
    tableE1.querySelectorAll('tbody tr').forEach(tr => {
      Array.from(tr.children).forEach(
        (td, ndx) => td.setAttribute('label', tdLabels[ndx])
      );
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Just got a typo. I'll correct asap.

Comment: I tried that and it removed all the label attributes.

Comment: Try again, there was a typo in the code, I can't tell the difference between a lower case 'L' and a '1'.

Comment: YES! it worked. THANKS. What did you change?

Comment: It was the variable tableEl, I typed it in as tableE1. Duh

Comment: I see you reordered it too. "tablesEl.forEach((tableE1) => {"... this was what I was missing. THANKS!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247756/discussion-between-adam-and-jottin).